# How to remove commits from branch only to cleanly add them later (without conflicts)?

Tags: git, merge

Let's say you have a repo that has the following merges:

```
master: -A-B-C-D
feature:    -C-D-E-F
```

What is the best way to remove merges C and D from master and later merge them back from the feature branch to master?

```
master: -A-B-
feature:    -C-D-E-F
```

The change needs to be done by a single pull request (no force pushing to master, renaming branches, etc) to the master branch.

When I try the following:

```sh
git checkout master
git checkout -b revert/feature
git revert -m 1 D
git revert -m 1 C
```

And push to remote feature, then merge feature back to master, there are merge conflicts and C and D remain reverted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reverted commits to be back, you need revert the revert commits itself.

```
git checkout master 
git checkout -b revert/feature 
git revert -m 1 D 
git revert -m 1 C
git checkout -b feature
git revert <git-revert-C-sha>
git revert <git-revert-D-sha>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try to create new branch from HEAD of master and then add your new commits from feature into that branch.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature_to_push
git cherry-pick hash-of-E
git cherry-pick hash-of-F
```